# Lambda expression C# Union Where

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I have objects of class

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

some have Error (and no Name and Age) some have no Error (and Name and Age)

```
Person[] p1 = new Person[] { new Person { Error = "Error1" }, new Person { Name = "Name1", Age = 1 } };



Person[] p2 = p1
                .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Error))
                .Select(
                    c => new Person { Name = c.Name, Age = c.Age }
                 ).ToArray()
                 Union()
                .Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Error))
                .Select(
                    d => new Person { Error = d.Error }
                 ).ToArray()
```

I need create second array p2, where I can select all persons objects from p1 which have Error, and Union all persons from same p1 which have no Error.

I need something like in code above, but it's not working. How can I write it in one lambda clause?

Thanks a lot?

Comment: Is this the query you wanted with correct syntax? `Person[] p2 = p1.Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Error)).Select(c => new Person { Name = c.Name, Age = c.Age }).Union(p1.Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Error)).Select(d => new Person { Error = d.Error })).ToArray();`

Comment: `but it's not working` why is that?

Comment: If you select all persons from `p1` which have `Error` and `Union` with all persons from `p1` which have `no Error`, you will get p1. :)

Comment: Yes, I need same result p1, it's just an example, in real there is xml input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found solution myself, it should be like:

```
Person[] p2 = p1
            .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Error))
            .Select(
                c => new Person { Name = c.Name, Age = c.Age }
             )
            .Union(
            p1.Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Error))
            .Select(
                d => new Person { Error = d.Error }
             )
             ).ToArray();
```

Sorry, maybe my answer was not so clear.
Thanks all for replies.

Answer (score 7):

```
p1.Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Error))
  .Union(p1.Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Error)))
  .ToArray()
```

You need to add the second `IEnumerable` inside the `.Union`. And no need to project again since the objects are already the type you need.

Although it's kind of moot in this case, the result is the same as `p1`

Comment: *maybe* the OP needs the projection, to guard against Persons that have both a Name and an Error (they will then lose the Name).

Comment: I need create new Person objects inside statement: c => new Person { Name = c.Name, Age = c.Age } or new Person { Error = d.Error } depending on Error status

Comment: In other words, I need like: if  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p1[i].Error)) { list.Add(new Person { Name = p[i].Name, Age = p[i].Age }) } else {list.Add(new Person { Error= p[i].Error }} , so in list new Person objects

Answer (score 2):

This will avoid cases where there is an Error but Name and Age have values or if there is no Error but Name and Age don't have values.

Separate:

```
var p1Err = p1.Where(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Error) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name) 
                   && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Age));
var p1NoErr = p1.Where(p => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Error) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name) 
                    && String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Age));

var p2 = p1Err.Union(p1NoErr)
              .ToArray();
```

Combined:

```
var p2 = p1.Where(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Error) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name) 
                   && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Age))
           .Union(p1.Where(ip => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ip.Error) 
                   && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ip.Name) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ip.Age)))
           .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is not actually what I need, because  
I need create new Person objects inside statement: c => new Person { Name = c.Name, Age = c.Age } or new Person { Error = d.Error } depending on Error status, and union/concat them